# Wordpress - erro ao iniciar o site

Tags: php, wordpress

Site em wordpress de um cliente de um colega saiu do ar.

Mensagem ao entrar no site:

> PHP Warning:  require(wp-includes/compat.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   E:\home\tecnoservicebr\web\wp-settings.php on line 71
>       PHP Warning:  require(wp-includes/compat.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   E:\home\tecnoservicebr\web\wp-settings.php on line 71
>       PHP Fatal error:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   'wp-includes/compat.php' (include_path='.;c:\php5\includes') in
>   E:\home\tecnoservicebr\web\wp-settings.php on line 71

Imagino que seja porque o wordpress está buscando o arquivo com o caminho local, porem não sei mudar isso, alguem pode me ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro não é do caminho do WordPress. No wp_settings.php ele chama esse arquivo com ABSPATH e por isso o caminho vai estar sempre certo.

Normalmente os erros com compat.php são causados por algum problema com o diretório wp_includes. Este arquivo é o primeiro que o WordPress tenta ler deste diretório e se o diretório está com algum problema dispara esse erro. Existem dois erros comuns:

1. Diretório não existe (provavelmente o seu caso)
2. Permissões do diretório/arquivos estão erradas

Nos dois casos a solução mais rápida e simples é:

1. Apagar a pasta wp-includes (se ela existir).
2. Baixar novamente o pacote de instalação de br.wordpress.org
3. Descompactar o pacote e subir apenas a pasta wp-includes por FTP sem se conectar como "root" (isso evita erros de permissão).
4. Conferir se as permissões da pasta wp-includes e subpastas são 755 e dos arquivos 644.

O 3 e 4 são um pouco diferentes se o seu servidor é Windows.